# extract words from a paragraph using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I want to extract information from each paragraph that begin with SET CURRENT and save the result as csv.
For example if I have the following code :

```
SET CURRENT = 'aaa' ;
CREATE SYN file1 FOR 1000.file1 ;
CREATE SYN file2 FOR 1000.file2 ;
CREATE SYN file3 FOR 1001.file3 ;
CREATE SYN file4 FOR 1001.file4 ;

SET CURRENT = 'bbb' ;
CREATE SYN file5 FOR 1002.file5 ;
CREATE SYN file6 FOR 1003.file6 ;
```

How can I get the following result

```
file1;SYN;1000.file1;aaa 
file2;SYN;1000.file2;aaa
file3;SYN;1001.file3;aaa
file4;SYN;1001.file4;aaa
file5;SYN;1002.file5;bbb
file6;SYN;1003.file6;bbb
```

I managed to get the information from the lines that begin with CREATE SYN but how can I add the information of the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this awk one-liner should give what you want:

```
awk -v q="'" -v OFS=";" '/^SET CUR/{split($0,a,q);v=a[2]}
                         /CREATE SY/{print $3,$2,$5,v}'    file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  awk -v q="'" -v OFS=";" '/^SET CUR/{split($0,a,q);v=a[2]}/CREATE SY/{print $3,$2,$5,v}' f
file1;SYN;1000.file1;aaa
file2;SYN;1000.file2;aaa
file3;SYN;1001.file3;aaa
file4;SYN;1001.file4;aaa
file5;SYN;1002.file5;bbb
file6;SYN;1003.file6;bbb
```

Comment: can you please explain you answer

Comment: @malmo it is pretty straightforward, split the `SET CU...` line by `'`, and get the aaa, bbb,  read `man gawk` the `split()` function